# Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I need to define that in the method AddOrEdit triggered a different method Add. The add method adds a new instance. But I catch the the error. The Add method works in debug. What am I doing wrong?

```
var repository = new Mock<IRepository>();
var layer = new Layer(repository.Object);

// Arrange
var object1=new Object1();
var object2=new Object2();
repository.Setup(a => a.Add<Object1>(new Object1(){Name="Name"}));

// Act
layer.AddOrEdit(object1, object2);

// Assert
repository.Verify(a => a.Add<Object1>(new Object1(){Name="Name"}));

public void AddOrEdit(Object1 object1, Object2 object2))
{
    ......
    ......
    Add(object2.Name)
}
public void Add(string name)
{
     Repository.Add(new Object1(){Name="Name"});
}
```

**Update:**

I removed

```
repository.Setup(a => a.Add<Object1>(new Object1(){Name="Name"}));
```

And override Equals

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var item = obj as Object1;

    return item != null && this.Name.Equals(item.Name);
}

repository.Verify(a => a.Add<Object1>(new Object1(){Name="Name1"})); // Test Failed
repository.Verify(a => a.Add<Object1>(new Object1(){Name="Name"}));  // Test Success
```

**Update2**
[Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17765935/2602098) offered a better solution

`repository.Verify(a => a.Add(It.Is<Object1>(y => y.Name == "Name")));`

Comment: Does your `Object1` type override Equals? If it doesn't, you're calling `Add` with a different argument to the one you were expecting..

Comment: Thx. Оverride Equals solved problem.

Comment: Are you sure you implemented your class correctly? Add method does not use the name parameter.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Tests behave properly

Comment: No need to override equals in your class just for testing.  See my answer which uses built in functionality of Moq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in your Verify call you should use

`It.Is<Object1>(y => y.Name == "Name")`

This should verify the call, and you won't need to override equals in your class just for testing purposes.

Comment: Thx. It's better than override equals